# If proxy is down, get a new one

Tags: bash, proxy

I'm writing my first bash script

```
LANG="en_US.UTF8" ; export LANG
PROXY=$(shuf -n 1 proxy.txt)
export https_proxy=$PROXY
RUID=$(php -f randuid.php)
curl --data "mydata${RUID}" --user-agent "myuseragent" https://myurl.com/url -o "ticket.txt"
```

This script also use curl, but if proxy is down it gives me this error:

> failed to connect PROXY:PORT

How can I make bash script run again, so it can get another proxy address from proxy.txt

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a loop which keeps running with different proxies until curl succeeds?

Comment: I actually know WHAT to do i just need HOW.
If curl timeouts or give "failed to connect to proxy" error so it runs again, but i'm not so into bash i'm more into php.
So i need bash for this, that's why i asked this question in a first place.
Thank you for your cooperation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run it in a loop until the `curl` succeeds, for example:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF8"
while true; do
    PROXY=$(shuf -n 1 proxy.txt)
    export https_proxy=$PROXY
    RUID=$(php -f randuid.php)
    curl --data "mydata${RUID}" --user-agent "myuseragent" https://myurl.com/url -o "ticket.txt" && break
done
```

Notice the `&& break` at the end of the `curl` command.
That is, if the `curl` succeeds, break out of the infinite loop.

If you have multiple `curl` commands and you need all of them to succeed,
then chain them all together with `&&`, and add the `break` after the last one:

```
curl url1 && \
curl url2 && \
break
```

Lastly, as @Inian pointed out,
you could use the `--proxy` flag to pass a proxy URL to `curl` without the extra step of setting `https_proxy`, for example:

```
curl --proxy "$(shuf -n 1 proxy.txt)" --data "mydata${RUID}" --user-agent "myuseragent"
```

Lastly, note that due to the randomness, a randomly selected proxy may come up more than once until you find one that works.
Avoid that, you could read iterate over the shuffled proxies instead of an infinite loop:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF8"
shuf proxy.txt | while read -r proxy; do
    ruid=$(php -f randuid.php)
    curl --proxy "$proxy" --data "mydata${ruid}" --user-agent "myuseragent" https://myurl.com/url -o "ticket.txt" && break
done
```

I also lowercased your user-defined variables,
as capitalization is not recommended for those.

Comment: Thank's a lot!
You're the best.
I actually have more than 1 curl command, do i add && break to it too?
Or break is added to the end of file? :/

Comment: I added another example to my post to answer that

Comment: @janos: `curl` supports a `--proxy` flag which can be used directly instead of export on every iteration.

Comment: The \ is to break the line, to make the script more readable. You could also do on one line without the \, but I wouldn't recommend that

Comment: HOw do I use proxy flag?

curl --proxy ${PROXY} or curl --proxy $PROXY

Comment: `${PROXY}` is the same as `${PROXY}`. Btw I added an example for this too.

Comment: @janos: Appreciate your attempt with `--proxy`, also one other optimization could be tracking the attempted combination from the proxy.txt file and removing it one at a time if it is not successful (or) keep track of status of all proxies from the file and once all of them are exhausted. re-try it after a while. But IMHO, it is not in the scope of the current answer.

Comment: It works, Another unwanted thing is this response

<html>
<head><title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.2</center>
</body>
</html>

How do i make it loop if curls succeed but get this response?

Comment: U forgot to tell how to clear previous output if failed and it repeats.
@janos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toFqrtDvBT4

Comment: @inian How to achieve to remove that shuffle line from proxy.txt if can't connect?

Answer (score 0):

I know i accepted @janos answer but since I can't edit his I'm going to add this

```
response=$(curl --proxy "$proxy" --silent --write-out "\n%{http_code}\n" https://myurl.com/url)
status_code=$(echo "$response" | sed -n '$p')
html=$(echo "$response" | sed '$d')
case "$status_code" in
    200) echo 'Working!'
         ;;
      *)
echo 'Not working, trying again!';
exec "$0" "$@"
esac
```

This will run my script again if it gives 503 status code which i wanted :)
And with @janos code it will run again if proxy is not working.
Thank you everyone i achieved what i wanted.

Comment: I think this is best option, without janos code beacuse script will run again if status is not 200. so this is my best solution